# Multiple icons in Android ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

Note that my activity is NOT extending ListActivity; just Activity.

I have a list view with a custom layout as follows:

(res/layout/list_item.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
>
<ImageView
 android:id="@+id/icon"
 android:layout_width="30dip"
 android:paddingTop="15dip"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:src="@drawable/icon_default"
/>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

I'm then setting the adapter for the ListView to an ArrayAdapter using an ArrayList, here called 'machines'.

```
ListView rooms = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.machines);
ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_item, android.R.id.text1, machines);
rooms.setAdapter(aa);
```

How would I go about doing a similar thing for the ImageView field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With an `ArrayAdapter`, you would need to override `getView()` and do more of the work yourself. You can either inflate the row yourself (g`etLayoutInflater().inflate()`) or chain to the superclass to get your row. Then, find the `ImageView` in the row and set its image based on the position parameter supplied to `getView()`. Return the resulting row.

[Here's a free excerpt](http://commonsware.com/Android/excerpt.pdf) from one of my books that covers much of this.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can create custom listview using base adapter